# am I using EPOCH time? python

Tags: python, datetime, epoch

As I need to transform the time format hh:mm to the count of minutes. Doing the maths would be:

hh*60+mm

I came across with the method `mktime`, which I thought it was to get the EPOCH time in minutes of a given `datetime`object. In this way I convert from `datetime`to `integer`.

I wrote this in order to calculate the time of the day in minutes:

(the outputs in the boxes below)

```
a = datetime.now()
print type(a)

print a
b= '2017-07-05 00:00:00.0'

b = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
type(b)
```

`out: type 'datetime.datetime'`

`out: type 'datetime.datetime'`

As both objects are `datetime` I used the method `mktime` that I found searching for a way to transform from `timestamp` to `integer`

```
timestamp = int(time.mktime(a.timetuple()))-int(time.mktime(b.timetuple()))
type(timestamp)
print timestamp
print a
print b
```

And the output is:

```
out: 62189
out: 2017-07-05 17:16:29.134026
out: 2017-07-05 00:00:00
```

So the value `62189`is seconds? Am I using EPOCH time?

(sorry if the question is bit fool, I am quite beginner, that's why I need help)

Thanks!

Comment: EPOCH is the number of seconds from 1/1/1970, and would be something like 1499273286. 62189 is the number of seconds from your two datetimes... that is, 17 hours, 16 minutes and 29 seconds is equivalent to 62189 seconds

Comment: @scsimon - No, "epoch" is an English word.  It basically means "the start of something".  The epoch here *is* 1/1/1970, or more precisely, `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.  The epoch is not the timestamp.  "Epoch Time" is a misnomer.

Comment: @Horacio - Normally when one capitalizes every letter of a word, they are indicating the word is an acronym.  The word "epoch" is just a regular English word.  It's a noun.  It doesn't need such treatment.  You are using it incorrectly also, see my comment to scsimon above.

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson, though i don't see how that changes my comment or makes it inaccurate when, as you stated, in this case it is what i described it as.

Comment: @scsimon - Yes, your basic assessment is correct.  Though note that assuming the OP is actually after a Unix Timestamp (commonly erroneously stated as "Epoch Time"), that the Unix Epoch is strictly UTC based. Since the OP is working with local time, so there's not really a value we can provide as an example without knowing the OP's time zone. :)

Comment: @Horacio - The answer to your question "Am I using EPOCH time?" is simply: No.

Answer (score 1):

I would come with a solution like:

```
import time
t = time.strptime("02:24", "%H:%M") # Replace "02:24" with your string parameter
nb_minutes = t.tm_hour * 60 + t.tm_min
```

This transforms the time format "hh:mm" to the count of minutes as requested in your OP.

Note that there is a distrinction between a date, a datetime and a time. Python offers more flexibility than Javascript Date() on this.

Basically:

date = YYYY-MM-DD

time = HH:MM:ss

datetime = YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss

Depending of your calculations, using the correct object in the python library will save you efforts all while making your source code more semantically readable.